# Почему не отрабатывает команда set?

Tags: cmd, bat

Здравствуйте подскажите пожалуйста почему не записывается переменная `D`
Пример кода прилагаю:

```
set D=Error   
for %%x in (D:\Test\DataFind\files\*) do (
echo %%~tx
set D=%%~tx
echo %D% 
)
pause
exit
```

Comment: Внимательно прочтите зачем нужно [setlocal](https://ab57.ru/cmdlist/setlocal.html). В ссылке приведены примеры, как надо использовать эту команду. Использование этого примера однозначно поможет решить проблему.

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо За подсказку 
Такой вариант Кода корректно работает

```
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set D=Error   
for %%x in (D:\Test\DataFind\files\*) do (
    echo %%~tx
    set D=%%~tx
    echo !D! 
)
pause
exit
```